# How to submit form only if some condition match from other form?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I am using AMP. I am asking mobile no of user and then `hit api(let's X)`. If response was success then showing result to the user and if response is `error then I asked otp`. After entering otp and clicking on verify I `hit api(let's Y)`. Response of api Y are followings.

```
Response code=200
code=1 or 2 or 3
Response code=400
Message:"some error"
```

On `success` response of api Y and `if code=1 then only I want to hit api X`. I don't know how to do this. Following is what I have done.

```
<form method="post"
      id="form1" 
      action-xhr="url of X api" 
      on="submit-error:otpScreen.show">
.
.
.
</form>
<form method="get"
      action-xhr="url of Y api"
      on="submit-success:event.response.code==1?form1.submit:otpScreen.hide"  //here i getting syntax error
>
<div id='otpScreen'>.......</div>
</form>
```

Is it even possible to submit second form on some condition from first form?

Answer (score 2):

You use amp-bind to disable the second form's submit button until the first one has been submitted. For example:

```
<form id=form1 on="submit-success:AMP.setState({form1Success: true})">...</form>
<form id=form2>
   ...
  <input type=submit disabled [disabled]="!form1Success">
</form>
```

... or you could hide the second form using the `hidden` attribute:

```
<form id=form1 on="submit-success:AMP.setState({form1Success: true})">...</form>
<form id=form2 hidden [hidden]="!form1Success">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: but this will not automatically submit form 2, I want to submit form 2 without user interaction if certain condition match(condition mention in question)

Comment: Didn't got that - that's even simpler. Updated the answer.